# bootstrap js-show-modal no me abre mas de 2 productos

Tags: bootstrap

tengo una plantilla en la cual en una misma pagina puedo poner varias imágenes y al hacer clic sobre  ellas (usando js-show-modal)me muestra una ventana popup con detalles. Estos detalles se colocan al final de la pagina y no se muestran hasta que no salga dicha ventana. el problema es que al inicio solo funcionaba con una imagen, luego logre que funcione con una imagen mas, pero no funciona con ninguna otra imagen. espero se pueda entender con el ejemplo siguiente y me puedan ayudar para poder hacer que salga un popup con los detalles de cada imagen:

tengo las imágenes que se muestran con la siguiente fuente:

```
<div class="row isotope-grid">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item conductor">
                <!-- Block2 -->
                <div class="block2">
                    <div class="block2-pic hov-img0" >
                        <img src="images/cable-1.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                        <a href="#" class="block2-btn flex-c-m stext-103 cl2 size-102 bg0 bor2 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-show-modal1">
                            Ver Detalles
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                        <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                            <a href="detalle-cable1.html" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6 js-show-modal1">
                                CONDUCTOR CABLEADO AAAC
                            </a>

                            <span class="stext-105 cl3">

                            </span>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
su detalle se coloca luego del footer y es llamado el js-modal1:


<div class="wrap-modal1 js-modal1 p-t-60 p-b-20">
        <div class="overlay-modal1 js-hide-modal1"></div>

        <div class="container">
                <div class="bg0 p-t-60 p-b-30 p-lr-15-lg how-pos3-parent">
                <button class="how-pos3 hov3 trans-04 js-hide-modal1">
                    <img src="images/icons/icon-close.png" alt="CLOSE">
                </button>
                <!-- d -->
                <div class="row">
                <!-- b -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 p-b-30">
                <div class="p-l-25 p-r-30 p-lr-0-lg">
                <div class="wrap-slick3 flex-sb flex-w">
                        <div class="wrap-slick3-dots"></div>
                        <div class="wrap-slick3-arrows flex-sb-m flex-w"></div>
        <!-- a -->
        <div class="slick3 gallery-lb">

                    <div class="item-slick3" data-thumb="images/cable-1.jpg">
                    <div class="wrap-pic-w pos-relative">

                    <img src="images/cable-1.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                    <a class="flex-c-m size-108 how-pos1 bor0 fs-16 cl10 bg0 hov-btn3 trans-04" href="images/cable-1.jpg">
                        <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="item-slick3" data-thumb="images/cable-2.jpg">
                    <div class="wrap-pic-w pos-relative">
                    <img src="images/cable-2.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                    <a class="flex-c-m size-108 how-pos1 bor0 fs-16 cl10 bg0 hov-btn3 trans-04" href="images/cable-2.jpg">
                        <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item-slick3" data-thumb="images/cable-3.jpg">
                    <div class="wrap-pic-w pos-relative">
                    <img src="images/cable-3.jpg" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                    <a class="flex-c-m size-108 how-pos1 bor0 fs-16 cl10 bg0 hov-btn3 trans-04" href="images/cable-3.jpg">
                        <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <!-- a -->
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- b -->

                <!-- c -->  
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 p-b-30">
                <div class="p-r-50 p-t-5 p-lr-0-lg">
                    <h4 class="mtext-105 cl2 js-name-detail p-b-14">
                            CONDUCTOR CABLEADO AAAC
                    </h4>

                    <span class="mtext-106 cl2">
                            ZTT, SKAITEKS, CENTELSA
                    </span>

                    <p class="stext-102 cl3 p-t-23">
                            Conductor cable desnudo aleación de aluminio de 25 a 120 mm2. De 7, 19 y 37 hilos con grasa o sin grasa.
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- c -->
                </div>
                <!-- d -->
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
el css que controla el modal es main.js:



     [ Show modal1 ]*/
    $('.js-show-modal1').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.js-modal1').addClass('show-modal1');
    });

    $('.js-hide-modal1').on('click',function(){
        $('.js-modal1').removeClass('show-modal1');
    });
```

```
y en main css:

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Modal1 ]*/
.wrap-modal1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  overflow: auto;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay-modal1 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.show-modal1 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```